# Can I put a Perl regex replacement string in a variable which references $1, $2, etc?

Tags: regex, perl

In this snippet, I want `$str1` and `$str2` to end up containing the same value (`"ba"`).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $replacement = '$2$1';

my $str1 = "ab";
my $str2 = "ab";

$str1 =~ s/(.)(.)/$2$1/g;
$str2 =~ s/(.)(.)/$replacement/g;

print "$str1\n$str2\n";
```

I want to be able to supply the `$replacement` pattern from user input, where the user can use `$1` and friends.

How can I make this work?

Comment: What do you mean by "use `$1`"?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/xbWaU9